# NG6 Angular sass files error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, gulp, webpack

I've started using **[NG6 Angular](https://github.com/AngularClass/NG6-starter)** recently and I kinda like it, but it got me stuck when I tried to use sass instead of its default styl coz it's what I use in my projects. I have installed all dependencies including **node-sass** and **sass-loader** you can check it **[here](https://github.com/PenAndPapers/Angular)**. Below are my configs and error when I test it using ***npm test***

**gulpfile.babel.js**

```
let paths = {
  js: resolveToComponents('**/*!(.spec.js).js'), // exclude spec files
  styl: resolveToApp('**/*.scss'), // stylesheets
};
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {},
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: [/app\/lib/, /node_modules/], loader: 'ng-annotate!babel' },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw' },
            { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style!css!sass' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // Injects bundles in your index.html instead of wiring all manually.
        // It also adds hash to all injected assets so we don't have problems
        // with cache purging during deployment.
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'client/index.html',
            inject: 'body',
            hash: true
        }),

        // Automatically move all modules defined outside of application directory to vendor bundle.
        // If you are using more complicated project structure, consider to specify common chunks manually.
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            minChunks: function(module, count) {
                return module.resource && module.resource.indexOf(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client')) === -1;
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

**error log**

```
START:
Hash: fcc86e1c1f5bc16638ec
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 3870ms
         Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
spec.bundle.js  4.42 MB       0  [emitted]  spec.bundle.js
chunk    {0} spec.bundle.js (spec.bundle.js) 1.68 MB [rendered]
    [0] ./spec.bundle.js 1.5 kB {0} [built]
    [1] ./~/angular/index.js 48 bytes {0} [built]
    [2] ./~/angular/angular.js 1.19 MB {0} [built]
    [3] ./~/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js 108 kB {0} [built]
    [4] ./client/app \.spec\.js 329 bytes {0} [built]
    [5] ./client/app/common/hero/hero.spec.js 1.77 kB {0} [optional] [built]
    [6] ./client/app/common/hero/hero.js 622 bytes {0} [built]
    [7] ./~/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js 367 kB {0} [built]
    [8] ./client/app/common/hero/hero.component.js 523 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
    [9] ./client/app/common/hero/hero.html 63 bytes {0} [built]
   [10] ./client/app/common/hero/hero.controller.js 481 bytes {0} [built]
   [11] ./~/babel-runtime/helpers/classCallCheck.js 208 bytes {0} [built]
   [13] ./client/app/common/navbar/navbar.spec.js 1.81 kB {0} [optional] [built]
   [14] ./client/app/common/navbar/navbar.js 640 bytes {0} [built]
   [15] ./client/app/common/navbar/navbar.component.js 549 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
   [16] ./client/app/common/navbar/navbar.html 63 bytes {0} [built]
   [17] ./client/app/common/navbar/navbar.controller.js 491 bytes {0} [built]
   [19] ./client/app/common/user/user.spec.js 1.77 kB {0} [optional] [built]
   [20] ./client/app/common/user/user.js 622 bytes {0} [built]
   [21] ./client/app/common/user/user.component.js 523 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
   [22] ./client/app/common/user/user.html 63 bytes {0} [built]
   [23] ./client/app/common/user/user.controller.js 481 bytes {0} [built]
   [25] ./client/app/components/about/about.spec.js 1.79 kB {0} [optional] [built]
   [26] ./client/app/components/about/about.js 766 bytes {0} [built]
   [27] ./client/app/components/about/about.component.js 536 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
   [28] ./client/app/components/about/about.html 180 bytes {0} [built]
   [29] ./client/app/components/about/about.controller.js 486 bytes {0} [built]
   [31] ./client/app/components/home/home.spec.js 1.77 kB {0} [optional] [built]
   [32] ./client/app/components/home/home.js 808 bytes {0} [built]
   [33] ./client/app/components/home/home.component.js 523 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
   [34] ./client/app/components/home/home.html 176 bytes {0} [built]
   [35] ./client/app/components/home/home.controller.js 481 bytes {0} [built]

ERROR in ./client/app/common/hero/hero.scss
Module parse failed: /development/sites/www/Angular/client/app/common/hero/hero.scss Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1573:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:727:47)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
 @ ./client/app/common/hero/hero.component.js 15:0-22

ERROR in ./client/app/common/navbar/navbar.scss
Module parse failed: /development/sites/www/Angular/client/app/common/navbar/navbar.scss Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1573:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:727:47)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
 @ ./client/app/common/navbar/navbar.component.js 15:0-24

ERROR in ./client/app/common/user/user.scss
Module parse failed: /development/sites/www/Angular/client/app/common/user/user.scss Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1573:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:727:47)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
 @ ./client/app/common/user/user.component.js 15:0-22

ERROR in ./client/app/components/about/about.scss
Module parse failed: /development/sites/www/Angular/client/app/components/about/about.scss Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1573:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:727:47)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
 @ ./client/app/components/about/about.component.js 15:0-23

ERROR in ./client/app/components/home/home.scss
Module parse failed: /development/sites/www/Angular/client/app/components/home/home.scss Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1573:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:727:47)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/development/sites/www/Angular/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
 @ ./client/app/components/home/home.component.js 15:0-22
21 10 2016 17:56:58.794:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:9876/
21 10 2016 17:56:58.800:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
21 10 2016 17:56:58.801:ERROR [launcher]: No binary for Chrome browser on your platform.
  Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env variable.

Finished in 0 secs / 0 secs

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I need also to replace this code section in **karma.conf.js**

**{ test: /\.styl$/, loader: 'style!css!stylus' },**

with

**{ test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style!css!*sass*' },**

now Im only getting chrome browser error since I dont have chrome installed

```
npm test

> ng6-starter@0.0.1 test /development/sites/www/Angular
> karma start


START:
24 10 2016 08:41:56.417:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:9876/
24 10 2016 08:41:56.424:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
24 10 2016 08:41:56.425:ERROR [launcher]: No binary for Chrome browser on your platform.
  Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env variable.

Finished in 0 secs / 0 secs
```